# Where to find android Manifest file in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

It might sound a bit simple but if you don't know where to look, how do you find the **AndroidManifest.xml** file within the **Xamarin Studio IDE**?

Answer (score 0):

I found mine (Using Xamarin Studio) in SolutionName\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml